# phpMyAdmin creating an attribute with '#" character in its name

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to create the following table.

```
CREATE TABLE customer
( 
cust# CHAR(3)NOT NULL , 
cname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL , 
city VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,   
PRIMARY KEY (cust#) 
)engine=InnoDB;
```

I am getting the following error
    #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'cname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL , city VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (cust#' at line 4

I have confirmed that the problem is with the '#' by replacing it with 'custNum'. 
However, I must use the '#' sign. I know I can rename the field in the myPhpAdmin interface to cust# but I need to know how to escape it in the SQL statement.

*Edit to say I have already tried '\#'

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to answer my own question and I'm posting here in case someone else has the same problem.
You have to use '`' around the name. So `cust#` did the trick.